# R read.csv loop with iterating variable in quotation marks

Tags: r, loops, data.table, stringr, read.csv

This is my code:

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
parameters <- c("conductivity","calcium","chloride","magnesium","phosphate","potassium","salinity","sodium","sulphate")
for (i in parameters){
  i <- read.csv(str_c("./Data/Parameters/",i,".csv"), sep=",", header=FALSE)
  i <- unique(i)
  i <- subset(i, select=c(1,2,4,6))
  i <- setnames(i, c("site","date", str_c("",i,""), "material"))
  i[,3] <- as.numeric(i[,3])
  i <- subset(i, i > 0)
}
```

Now, there are two things that don't work here. 
The first is in the `setnames` function: it doesn't understand that it needs to label one of the columns of the CSV with the variable name.
The second is that it doesn't actually call the imported files with 'conductivity', 'calcium', etc but simply calls them all 'i'.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `map`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(parameters, ~ read_csv(str_c("./Data/Parameters/", .x, ".csv")) %>%
               distinct %>%
                select(1, 2, 4, 6) %>%
                rename_at(3, ~  .x) %>%
                mutate(!! .x := !! rlang::sym(.x)) %>%
                filter_at(vars(.x), any_vars(. > 0))
           )
```

Comment: Parsed with column specification:
cols(
  `R.OUSE A422 RD.BR.BRACKLEY` = col_character(),
  `2000-01-24T10:55:00` = col_datetime(format = ""),
  `Conductivity at 25 C` = col_character(),
  `812` = col_double(),
  `us/cm` = col_character(),
  `RIVER / RUNNING SURFACE WATER` = col_character(),
  `ENVIRONMENTAL MONITORING STATUTORY (EU DIRECTIVES)` = col_character(),
  `459427` = col_double(),
  `236819` = col_double()
)

Comment: Warning: 8872 parsing failures.
   row                 col   expected     actual                                 file
652814 2000-01-24T10:55:00 date like  18/11/2016 './Data/Parameters/conductivity.csv'
652815 2000-01-24T10:55:00 date like  06/12/2016 './Data/Parameters/conductivity.csv'
652816 2000-01-24T10:55:00 date like  06/12/2016 './Data/Parameters/conductivity.csv'
652817 2000-01-24T10:55:00 date like  05/01/2017 './Data/Parameters/conductivity.csv'
652818 2000-01-24T10:55:00 date like  20/01/2017 './Data/Parameters/conductivity.csv'
See problems(...) for more details.

Comment: Error: object 'conductivity' not found

Comment: @NicolaGambaro that may be because. you don't have. that file with the same name

Comment: I definitely do though

Comment: @NicolaGambaro `R` is case-sensitive.  So please check whether there is any case differences

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
parameters <- c("conductivity","calcium","chloride","magnesium","phosphate",
    "potassium","salinity","sodium","sulphate")
lapply(parameters, function(x) {
    DT <- unique(fread(paste0("./Data/Parameters/", x, ".csv"), header=FALSE))[,
        V4 := as.numeric(V4)][
            V4 > 0, paste0("V", c(1,2,4,6))]
    setnames(DT, names(DT), c("site","date", x, "material"))
})
```